# Facebook Graph API: Handling Timeouts and Errors

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a program that makes a lot of fql and graph calls and I'm not sure how to handle when there's a 'get' error or a 'post' error. How do I get it to retry? I'm still new to this stuff but could I use some sort of try catch block? if so, how do I structure it?

I guess this could be extended to any get timeout in javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Querying Facebook Graph API can be a real pain.  First of all, I try to chop my queries in batches. For instance, if I want all of my friends' posts, I first get an array of all my friends, then create queries for their posts for 10 friends each and send them off to facebook.  What I do is with every reponse is test if there's an error in the response and if so I restart the function that generates the batches and sends them.  I use one counter that keeps track of the amount of queries send out.  If I send out 10 queries and I'm getting only 9, I restart the function after 30 seconds again.  I use another counter that after 3 retries I show an error to the user...